# Dumping Stack Overflow to a private network

Tags: support, data-dump, creative-commons

Is there any tool to use the Stack Overflow Creative Commons data dumps to serve as the same Stack Overflow format website, but only on a private network (for example, running locally over Apache).

Currently I've downloaded Creative Commons data dumps, but it contains only XML files with no user interface and database engine provided to use these XML files.

Is there any easy way for me do you it, without needing to write the user interface and database queries on my own?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/web-applications-inspired-by-stack-exchanges-system

Comment: StackExchange is not designed to run locally/offline - while I expect it's possible it goes against the SE ethic of being open and accessible to all.

Comment: @tombull so SE is closed source for ethical reasons? Not sure I follow that logic. :) (not that I mind SE being closed source. I've always thought it was the right decision.)

Answer (score 7):

The answer is no, because the SE engine is not publicly available.

[Stack Overflow Enterprise is available](https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/enterprise) for internal use, but that is for large organizations only.

[These clones](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/web-applications-inspired-by-stack-exchanges-system) may help you, many of them are open-source

But they most probably rely on a different DB model, so you would have to do a major revamp of the dumps  and import.

Comment: Oh damn, can't even spell "engine".. And to think that I dreamt of driving one as a kid :P

Answer (score 6):

[OSQA](http://www.osqa.net/), an open source clone of the SO model, seems to have a [Stack Exchange import tool.](http://meta.osqa.net/questions/5322/how-do-i-access-the-stackexchange-migration-tool)